# How i can slice Nodeiterator in python ? I

Tags: python, slice, object-slicing, instaloader, type-slicing

I want to download followers of an instagram account using instaloader ,but the profile i want to scrape contains almost 800 followers and instaloader allows me to scrape 200 followers for single code run and i have to run same code again and again.Now i want to slice nodeiterator object in python so that i can start scraping followers from 200 to 800 instead of 1 to 800.

Check my code :

followers=profile.get_followers()

i want like thi

followers=profile.get_followers()[200:]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @NilsWerner this show me

Nodeiterator object is not subscriptable